# How to use difflib independently from position?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, difflib

So, I have this code

```
import difflib

list1 = ["ameixa","bolo","guarana","caju","pizza","maracuja","forro", "coco"]
list2 = ["ameixa","guarana","caju","pizza","maracuja","forro","bolo"]

for line in difflib.unified_diff(list1, list2, fromfile='file1', tofile="file2", lineterm=""):
    print(line)
```

The problem is: Is returning that:

```
--- file1
+++ file2
@@ -1,8 +1,7 @@
 ameixa
-bolo
 guarana
 caju
 pizza
 maracuja
 forro
-coco
+bolo
```

So, as you see, "Bolo" is on both of the lists but it's recognizing as a different element for both lists. How can I compare both of them without taking the position into consideration?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to transform the two lists into `sets` and make them again into `list` format:

```
list1 = list(set(list1))
list2 = list(set(list2))
```

**Output 1**

```
>>> print(list1)
... ['caju', 'forro', 'coco', 'ameixa', 'pizza', 'maracuja', 'bolo', 'guarana']
>>> print(list2)
... ['caju', 'forro', 'ameixa', 'pizza', 'maracuja', 'bolo', 'guarana']
```

And when we apply the script we get:

```
for line in difflib.unified_diff(list1, list2, fromfile='file1', tofile="file2", lineterm=""):
    print(line)
```

**Output 2**

```
--- file1
+++ file2
@@ -1,6 +1,5 @@
 caju
 forro
-coco
 ameixa
 pizza
 maracuja
```

Comment: thanks, but that would only work with strings that have the same size. What about strings that don't have the same size? Like
list1 = ["ameixa","bolo","guarana","caju","pizza","maracuja","forro", "coco"]
list2 = ["caju","pizza","maracuja","forro","bolo"]
The output would be different. Got it?

Comment: @patrick001p I think it works also when the two sizes are not equal, I got the following output :  `--- file1
+++ file2
@@ -1,8 +1,5 @@
 maracuja
-coco
-ameixa
 pizza
-guarana
 bolo
 caju
 forro
`

Comment: yes, sorry. I made a mistake. It works!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sort the lists before running `difflib.unified_diff`.

```
for line in difflib.unified_diff(sorted(list1), sorted(list2), fromfile='file1', tofile="file2", lineterm=""):
    print(line)
```

**Output:**

```
--- file1
+++ file2
@@ -1,7 +1,6 @@
 ameixa
 bolo
 caju
-coco
 forro
 guarana
 maracuja
```

**EDIT:**

This is a solution without using `difflib.unified_diff`, which is maybe simpler. From the question is not so clear what is exactly what you want as output, though:

```
# Find elements in list1 that are missing in list2
one_not_two = set(list1).difference(list2)
# Find elements in list2 that are missing in list1
two_not_one = set(list2).difference(list1)
# Find elements in common
one_and_two = set(list1).intersection(list2)
```

Comment: I don't think it would work for strings in different sizes, for instance

list1 = ["ameixa","bolo","guarana","caju","pizza","maracuja","forro", "coco"]
list2 = ["pizza","maracuja"]

It would say that the all the elements of the list2 doesnt belong in list1

Comment: @patrick001p See my edited answer. It might offer a better solution than using `difflib`.